# Strange behaviour with a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, vector

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the output that I get when I run this simple piece of code

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "LxUNIXsys.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  //memory management class
  LxUNIXsys mem_manager;

  vector <double*> vec;

  mem_manager.DumpMemoryInfo();getchar();
  for(int i =0; i < 3; i++) vec.push_back(new double (3));
  for(int i =0; i < vec.size(); i++) cout << *vec[i] << endl;
  mem_manager.DumpMemoryInfo();getchar();
  for(int i =0; i < vec.size(); i++) delete vec[i];
  vec.clear();
  for(int i =0; i < 3; i++) cout << *vec[i] << endl;
  cout <<"size of vec " <<vec.size() << endl;
  mem_manager.DumpMemoryInfo();

  return 0;
}
```

The LxUNIXsys is a class that I'm using for the memory dump and the method I'm calling from it is:

```
void LxUNIXsys::DumpMemoryInfo() {

  pid_t id = getpid();
  //  cout << "id = " << id << endl;
  stringstream ss("");
  ss << "pmap -d " << id  << " | grep private ";
  //  cout << ss.str().c_str() << endl;
  cout << "Memory dump: [pid = " << id << " ] " << flush; system(ss.str().c_str());
}
```

The Output I'm getting is:

```
Memory dump: [pid = 17012 ] mapped: 51476K    writeable/private: 7452K    shared: 0K

3
3
3
Memory dump: [pid = 17012 ] mapped: 51480K    writeable/private: 7456K    shared: 0K

3
3
3
size of vec 0
Memory dump: [pid = 17012 ] mapped: 51480K    writeable/private: 7456K    shared: 0K
```

So, basically I deleted the pointer and not only the information is still there but I can access it after `clear()`.

I have also tried to delete vec using `delete[]` but the result is the same.

PS: I know about the existence of smart pointers, but I want to know why this code does not do what's expected.

PPS: I know about the undefined behavior, forget about the accessing after clear, I just want an effective way to release the memory immediately, like when I delete a regular pointer.

Comment: You know you're doing the wrong thing, why are you surprised about the results?

Comment: delete does not clear its internal data.

Comment: You are focusing on the wrong thing. Read my other comments, please.

Answer (score 4):

You have **undefined behaviour**. This is caused by you accessing elements of your `std::vector` that just don't exist. Undefined behaviour means that anything can happen. It can even appear that objects that should have been destroyed are still there.

The C++ standard says nothing about how the operating system should manage the allocation and deallocation of memory. It simply gives rules about what your program can rely on. There's no reason that the memory allocated for those three `double`s couldn't actually be reclaimed by the OS a little later than you asked for it to be. You just can't rely on it any more. The only thing you can rely on is that you should not be accessing outside the bounds of your `std::vector`.

This is precisely why this is specified by the standard as undefined behaviour. It gives the operating system or environment the leeway to perform its memory management however it chooses, while still giving your program that rules to rely on for well-defined behaviour.

Comment: So, why doesn't the memory go down?

Comment: But I have an algorithm that needs to have a similar type of vector freed immediately within an iteration of a for cycle. Is there a way to do that with this approach? When I delete a pointer not within a vector, the memory is immediately released...

Comment: @Gonçalo Trust your compiler and operating system to manage this for you. Just write the code and only afterwards, if you *measure* that there's a performance problem, should you start looking into this. I bet that there's no problem at all. Your iterations may just reuse the allocated memory.

Comment: That's exactly why I am asking this question. I'm doing a physics simulation that requires a lot of data to be stored in each for cycle, treated and then freed quickly. The behavior I'm having now is of a for cycle that, after calling the deletion of all the vectors I'm using, just keeps on filling the RAM and not clearing it.

Comment: @Gonçalo: Are you sure you're deleting everything you allocate? The free store *should* manage to reuse the memory that's been deleted without filling the RAM. If you have a memory leak, then a tool like Valgrind might help track it down.

Comment: I'm printing the memory used in the code above, as you can see, it does not go down. How can I make it go down and be sure that it goes down? I tried raising the size of vec to 50000 but the behavior is the same...

Comment: @Gonçalo you're printing the memory allocated to the process by the OS, which (as at least two answers explain) is not usually released back to the OS since that would be too inefficient. Deleted memory is kept by the process for reuse. If you find that the amount keeps growing, then you have a memory leak that needs fixing. If it doesn't, then why do you care whether it's released to the OS immediately?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting memory that was allocated from the free store is not guaranteed to return it to the operating system, or to make it inaccessible. Typically, small allocations are managed by a heap within your process; it allocates a large lump from the system, and allocates smaller pieces of that; deleted memory is returned to that heap. This can be much more efficient than going to the system for every allocation.

This means that deleted memory may still be accessible and, until it's reused, may still contain whatever data was there when it was deleted. So accessing it gives undefined behaviour, not any well-defined error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the way you are reading your vector:

```
for(int i =0; i < 3; i++)
```

With this line you are reading beyond the end of the vector.
Even if it's content is deleted, it may stay in memory for a while. This means that once it is deleted, you can no longer be sure that what is hold in those positions is what was stored before deletion, but it CAN be what you stored.

It's like deleting a file from your HD. The bits ar eactually there until rewritten, they are just set as unused.