# Strange error regarding STL vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, stl

I've a small code snippet which produces an error on running. The following code stores data of mystruct and creates a vector of pointers which store the addresses of the corresponding data.

```
struct mystruct{
  std::vector < int > someinfo;
  int somenumbers;
  double *somepointer;
  double someparm;
  void Print(){....}
};

void DoSomething(mystruct &_somestruct, std::vector< mystruct > &_somevec,
         std::vector<mystruct *> &_ptr){
  _somevec.push_back(_somestruct);
  _ptr.push_back(&(_somevec.back()));
}

void ReadStruct(){
  std::vector<mystruct > _vec;
  std::vector<mystruct *> _ptr;

  for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    mystruct _struct;

    _struct.somenumbers = 3;
    _struct.someinfo.push_back(0);
    _struct.someinfo.push_back(1);
    _struct.someinfo.push_back(2);

    DoSomething(_struct, _vec, _ptr);
  }
  _vec[0].Print(); //Prints correctly
  _ptr[0]->Print();//Prints garbage info
}
```

If I first create the vector and then create the vector of pointers then the code works perfectly i.e.

```
void DoSomething(mystruct &_somestruct, std::vector< mystruct > &_somevec){
  _somevec.push_back(_somestruct);
  //_ptr.push_back(&(_somevec.back()));
}
void DoSomething1(std::vector< mystruct > &_somevec, std::vector<mystruct *> &_ptr){
  for(int i=0;i<_somevec.size();i++)
    _ptr.push_back(&(_somevec[i]));
}
```

I do not know what mistake I am doing. Your help/inputs is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Please indent your code so that it's readable.  Thanks.

Comment: the pointer version is undefined behavior, as `_struct` is out of scope and destructed after each iteration of the loop, the non pointer version works by copying the struct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange behaviour with a vector of pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899040/strange-behaviour-with-a-vector-of-pointers)

Comment: @Mgetz But isn't it stored in _somevec? I am storing the address of _somevec.

Comment: @SumanVajjala no, `_somevec` stores a copy not the original structure if you intend to store a pointer you should explicitly allocate it on the heap using `new`

Answer (score 2):

This does not look very safe to me.

In `_ptr.push_back(&(_somevec.back()));` you are taking the address of an element in `_somevec`. But when `_somevec` is changed by e.g. a `push_back` the address will be invalid!

For example this will not work:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(17);
int* p = &v.back(); // pointer is valid
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) v.push_back(0);
*p = 42; // ERROR: p is no longer valid!
```

You can make this a bit better by using `reserve` prior to using `push_back`.

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve(100); // v will now have enough room to not reallocate memory
v.push_back(17);
int* p = &v.back(); // pointer is valid
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) v.push_back(0);
*p = 42; // (probably) OK: p is still valid
```

But I would not recommend to do this.

Comment: Even if I give _ptr.push_back(&(_somevec[_somevec.size()-1])) I get the same error. Will the address of an already stored element in _somevec change when a new element is added?

Comment: Yes it will if the vector needs to reallocate its memory.

Comment: Ok. So if the vector expands then it may shift it's old contents to an entirely new location. That explains the failure then. Thank you

Comment: @SumanVajjala If that answers your question, then please accept the answer. Here at StackOverflow we don't say thank you; we accept and upvote answers instead.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you are inserting elements into one vector and reference them with pointers from another vector. However, there doesn't seem to be any precaution against the vector of objects running out of capacity and relocating the objects, invalidating all the pointer.

The easiest approach to verify this hypothesis is to see if the `capacity()` of the vector of objects ever changes. The easiest fix is probably to use a `std::deque<mystruct>` as a `std::deque<T>` doesn't relocate its objects when adding/removing objects at either end.

Comment: Kuhl Thank you for your inputs. Does the vector store the objects in a contiguous way in memory? Is it because of the scattered storage that std::deque works here?

Comment: Yes, `std::vector<T>` uses a contiguous sequence of values while `std::deque<T>` uses an array of equal sized arrays, i.e., it doesn't need to move existing objects when it runs out of space.